# python argparse sub parser

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script that responds to 1 command and 1 sub argument:

`command1` and `command1 plugins`

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# command1 (i.e. (--help,) --version)
parser.add_argument('--version', dest="version", action="store_true", default=False, help="Print the version.")

# command1 plugins (i.e. (--help,) --update, --upgrade) which it loads from another python file
parser = plugins_cmd.add_parsers(parser)
```

Both have their own arguments you can pass, now I would like to add this sub argument:

`command1 google ((--help,) --auth, --refresh)`

I added the following, which I hoped to add an extra sub argument google.

```py
# command1 google (--help)
parser2 = google_cmd.add_parsers(parser)
```

Comment: does any of this code run?  what errors?

Comment: I don't what this `add_parsers` method does.  A `subparsers` Action class has a `add_parser` method, but that takes a string, not a working parser object.  It's hard to tell what code is actually working, possibly using other modules, and what code is just wishful thinking.

Comment: The plugin_cmd.add_parser is a function loaded from plugin_cmd. Thats where the --version is been set with a different 'add_argument'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The official subparsers mechanism is documented at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands.  If you are  using something else, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution for this.

```py
def add_parsers(parser):
        """
        Adds the plugins and google subcommands to a given argparse.ArgumentParser
        """
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

        # Add parsers from plugins_cmd
        plugins_cmd.add_parsers(subparsers)

        # Add parsers from google_cmd
        google_cmd.add_parsers(subparsers)

add_parsers(parser)
```